# Circuitikz works with ground but does not work for rground

Tags: pgfplots, errors, circuitikz

If I try to plot the following circuitikz schematic it works:

```
\begin{figure}[bth]
    \myfloatalign
    \begin{center}
    \begin{circuitikz}[american voltages]
    \draw
        (0,0) node[ground] {}
        to [V, l^=$F_{A}$] (0,2)
        to [R, i^>=$v_A$, -o, l_=$Z_A$] (3,2);
    \end{circuitikz}
    \end{center}
    \caption{Circuit representation of the actuator.}
    \label{fig:actuatormodel}
\end{figure}
```

But when I want to use rground or sground instead of ground (I saw these nicer ground symbols in the [circuitikz manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/contrib/circuitikz/circuitikzmanual.pdf)), I get the following error when compiling:

```
Latex Error: ./chapters/design.tex:38 Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tikz/rground' and I am going to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it.
```

In my document setup I load tikz, circuitikz and pgfplots like this:

```
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{chains, shapes, arrows}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{legend style={font=\smaller}, compat=newest, plot coordinates/math parser=false}
\usepgflibrary{arrows}
\usepackage[siunitx]{circuitikz}
```

I use the MacTeX-2012 Distribution. Why can I use ground but not rground?

Comment: It works with no problems in my system (TeX Live2013) using `circuitikz.sty    2012/12/29 The CircuiTikz circuit drawing package version 0.3.0` Which version of `circuitikz` do you use?

Comment: I saw that I actually have the MacTeX-2012 Distribution with CircuiTikz 0.2.4. I am updating now to the MacTeX-2013 Distribution, hopefully that will solve my problem.

Comment: Please provide a [minimal example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) next time. And if your problem is not solved with the update do provide a minimal example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was solved by updating MacTeX to the MacTeX-2013 Distribution. This updated CircuiTikz from version 0.2.4 to version 0.3.0.